# What to do after change HTTP to HTTPS?

Tags: ssl, https

I've a website working good from a couple of years. Now I'd like to implement ssl protection, for Facebook app and payment stuff.
My question is if I've to change inside the code all the http url to https url.
Or, with your experience, what I've to modify in my code? (htaccess? link? ecc)

Thanks in advance.

Alex

Comment: Have you tried googleing it ?

Comment: Yes, but I was hoping someone makes me more clearness.

Comment: Number1 => you have to give us what is your OS Server ?
Number2 => what is your service Server ? "Nginx" "Apache" ??

Comment: Os: Linux, service server: Apache

Comment: have u purshased a certeficate keys ? or not yet ?

Comment: if not here is some sites www.geotrust.com , www.thawte.fr (this google uses that site for its certeficates) ...

Comment: Not yet. Before I wanted take information about it. I'm in Italy. I'm buying an IP and then a ssl certificate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Good article on SSL might give you a better understanding of how it works.

http://info.ssl.com/article.aspx?id=10694

Answer (score 0):

here is the documentation for your parameters !

[Install SSL on Apache Linux](http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2011/03/install-apache2-ssl/)

turn your `apache` to `apache_mod_ssl`